# Is there a way to get a wordpress user's metadata using an external script

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to make a script that when it receives a post request with the username and password then it checks if the username and password are correct then it finds the number of coins the user has (i use a plugin called [MoolaMojo](https://co.wordpress.org/plugins/moolamojo/)) and sends it back in a JSON string. The PHP script is under the same domain but is not affiliated with WP.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

// Load Request
$api_method = isset($_POST['api_method']) ? $_POST['api_method'] : '';
$api_data = isset($_POST['api_data']) ? $_POST['api_data'] : '';

// Validate Request
if (empty($api_method) || empty($api_data)) {
    API_Response(true, 'Invalid Request');
}
if (!function_exists($api_method)) {
    API_Response(true, 'API Method Not Implemented');
}

// Call API Method
call_user_func($api_method, $api_data);

/* Helper Function */

function API_Response($isError, $errorMessage, $responseData = '')
{
    exit(json_encode(array(
        'IsError' => $isError,
        'ErrorMessage' => $errorMessage,
        'ResponseData' => $responseData
    )));
}

/* API Methods */

function loginUser($api_data)
{
    // Decode Login Data
    $login_data = json_decode($api_data);

    // Dummy Check
    if ($login_data->username == 'test' &&
        $login_data->password == '1234')
    {
        // Success
        API_Response(false, '', 'SUCCESS');
    }
    else
    {
        // Error
        API_Response(true, 'Invalid username and/or password.');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: yes there is, all the data is stored in the database only. you can first match the username and password(md5) if thats correct then get the user id and fetch all the metadata. run a foreach loop and find the relevant metadata and return it

Comment: @ShashankShekhar Okay, how would i do this?

Comment: For what it's worth, WordPress provides the [foundation for developing REST APIs](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/). You could integrate functionality directly into WordPress with a plugin or code snippet. Sad to say, explaining how to do all that is *far* beyond the scope of a Stack Overflow answer. Maybe somebody on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com knows a plugin or other pre-built way to do what you want.